# How to determine if you have an internet connection in R

Tags: r

Sometimes I need to download data from the internet. On occasions this has failed either because the website is down or because my computer has lost its internet connection.

Question: Is there some function in R which will return TRUE/FALSE as to whether I am connected to the internet?

Comment: What operating system? In Windows I think you'd have to run ipconfig from a shell, and on Linux it would be ifconfig. You'd then have to parse the output and test.

Comment: The ability to download data from a remote machine depends on so many factors which are outside of the control of your code, and whose state may change at any time. The only 100% certain way to know if you can download the file is to attempt to download it, and succeed. Even if you can start a transfer, it doesn't guarantee that the net connection won't go down part way through, so you need to write code to cope with this situation anyway. So just write that code, and ditch trying to detect beforehand whether you'll succeed.

Comment: A more elegant method is testing dns via `utils::nsl` (unix only) or `curl::nslookup` (cross-platform).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is an attempt at parsing the output from ipconfig/ifconfig, as suggested by Spacedman.

```
havingIP <- function() {
  if (.Platform$OS.type == "windows") {
    ipmessage <- system("ipconfig", intern = TRUE)
  } else {
    ipmessage <- system("ifconfig", intern = TRUE)
  }
  validIP <- "((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)[.]){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)"
  any(grep(validIP, ipmessage))
}
```

With a simple TRUE/FALSE output

```
> havingIP()
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I don't suppose i[pf]config return a useful return value if the interface isn't up? It's not mentioned in the ifconfig man page, and I don't want to take my box's network down to test because I'm logging on remotely and I'd probably kill my connection :)

Comment: If the return value from the system is not containing a valid IP the function returns FALSE. Thus, f.e.x. now home using Linux I get FALSE due to the fact that I need to be root to use ifconfig. I get "sh: ifconfig: not found" is echoed to the R terminal before the FALSE return value.

Comment: At least on my computer (Mint based on linux 3.13) , this can return TRUE when no internet connection.

Comment: This does not check if you have an active internet connection. It checks if you have a valid IP Address. I just turned off my wifi and this still returns TRUE.

Comment: AFAI understand this correctly, ifconfig returns useful information (a character string) regardless of connection (Being on a macbook osx 10.14)

Answer (score 36):

The `curl` package has a function `has_internet` which tests by performing a `nslookup`:

```
curl::has_internet
## function(){
##    !is.null(nslookup("google.com", error = FALSE))
## }
```

Testing DNS is faster and may be more reliable than retrieving a URL because the latter might fail for unrelated reasons (e.g. firewall, server down, etc).

Comment: For whatever reason it seems that `curl::has_internet()` function returns false when standard dns utilities and system curl can work OK. It appears that `curl::nslookup()` function is more reliable, hence Jeroens function is preferable for me (gives more consitent results). I am observing this in a starbucks coffee shop, btw.

Answer (score 29):

A dirty work around would be using `RCurl::getURL` function.

```
if (is.character(getURL("www.google.com"))) {
    out <- TRUE
} else {
    out <- FALSE
}
```

Comment: Could be shortened to: `out <- is.character(getURL("www.google.com"))`

Comment: Thank you for improving my ragged solution.

Comment: actually when no network getURL issues an error, you should use `out <-try(is.character(getURL("www.google.com"))) == TRUE`

Comment: See my answer below for a more elegant solution in the `curl` package.

Comment: Another alternative: 
`out<-RCurl::url.exists("https://www.google.com")`


This is TRUE only if internet available

Comment: The url.exists() approach seems to work better for my use case that involves a legacy piece of code where only RCurl, not curl, package is available - the getURL(...) approach led to raising an error, not returning FALSE. Which was rather inconvenient.

Answer (score 11):

Just another one to add to the pot, inspired by @romans answer, this works only on Windows I'd assume, not sure about other platforms:

```
canPingSite <- function(test.site) {
    !as.logical(system(paste("ping", test.site)))
}
```

Which we test as follows:

```
> t1 <- canPingSite("www.yahoo.com")
[...]

> t2 <- canPingSite(";lkjsdflakjdlfhasdfhsad;fs;adjfsdlk")
[...]

> t1; t2
[1] TRUE
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: I got two downvotes for this, but I can't work out why? I don't care about reputation points (they are meaningless to me), but I would like to understand what's bad about this solution. My reasoning for the downvotes would be because this solution will only work on windows, which I guess is sort of fair enough :)

Comment: Like this one, on Linux just adapt to: `canPingSite <- function(test.site) { !as.logical(system(paste("ping -c 1", test.site))) }`

Comment: I'd suggest adding `ping -n 1` because we don't need to do the standard 4 pings. I'm not patient enough to wait for 4 separate responses ;)

Answer (score 7):

Do it with just two lines of code:

```
install.packages('pingr')
pingr::is_online()
```

Comment: As it is, you don't need line 2.

Comment: You're welcome. The `::` operator takes care of that.

Comment: Cheers. I knew it escaped you :)

Answer (score 7):

All these answers use packages or code outside of base R.  Here's how to do it with just base R:

```r
# IANA's test website
is_online <- function(site="http://example.com/") {
  tryCatch({
    readLines(site,n=1)
    TRUE
  },
  warning = function(w) invokeRestart("muffleWarning"),
  error = function(e) FALSE)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Bioconductor's Biobase package has a function for testing internet connection.

```
Biobase::testBioCConnection()
```

Below is a heavily modified version of this function for testing ability to read lines from a URL.

```
can_internet <- function(url = "http://www.google.com") {

    # test the http capabilities of the current R build
    if (!capabilities(what = "http/ftp")) return(FALSE)

    # test connection by trying to read first line of url
    test <- try(suppressWarnings(readLines(url, n = 1)), silent = TRUE)

    # return FALSE if test inherits 'try-error' class
    !inherits(test, "try-error")
}

can_internet()
```

Answer (score 1):

As the function above from eyjo

```
havingIP <- function() {
 if (.Platform$OS.type == "windows") {
   ipmessage <- system("ipconfig", intern = TRUE)
 } else {
   ipmessage <- system("ifconfig", intern = TRUE)
 }
 validIP <- "((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)[.]){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)"
 any(grep(validIP, ipmessage))
}
```

also returns true for localhost ip "127.0.0.1" it needs to be removed to prevent false positives. For example as shown below:

```
 havingIP <- function() {
 if (.Platform$OS.type == "windows") {
   ipmessage <- system("ipconfig", intern = TRUE)
 } else {
   ipmessage <- system("ifconfig", intern = TRUE)
 }
 validIP <- "((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)[.]){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)"
 any(grep(validIP, ipmessage[-grep("127.0.0.1", ipmessage)]))
}
```

But even better would be a solution that prevents localhosts by modifying the regex of validIP.

Comment: This last does not work for me; now it says FALSE even when I do have internet.

Answer (score 0):

This is a version of eyjo's answer which sacrifices accuracy for speed.

```
IPavailable <- function() {
  cmd <- switch(.Platform$OS.type, "windows" = "ipconfig", "ifconfig")
  any(grep("(\\d+(\\.|$)){4}", system(cmd, intern = TRUE)))
}
```