# getSymbols from quantmod not working from command line

Tags: r, quantmod

I have been able to use the getSymbols function to draw financial data from the default source (yahoo) successfully from within RStudio. When I tried to run this in a script from the command line, this fails and returns no data. The same when I manually enter the command from the command line.

Code:

```
library(quantmod)
args <- commandArgs(FALSE)
options("getSymbols.warning4.0"=FALSE)
getSymbols("APL")
chartSeries(APL, subset='last 1 months')
saveChart('png')
```

Error:

```
Error in download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m, : 
unable to connect to 'chart.yahoo.com' on port 80.
```

I'm executing this from a VM running Windows Server 2008. Any ideas? I want to be able to call this code from PHP to update a figure when the user visits a page

Comment: This is problem with your internet connection. It has nothing to do with `getSymbols`, quantmod, or R. I'll guess that you're behind a proxy.

Comment: Joshua - yes, I am. But why would it block access from command line but not from RStudio?

Comment: Because someone configured the RStudio server to use the proxy...

Comment: In the same RStudio session I can successfully pull using quantmod:getSymbols, however cannot get connection using RCurl:getURL for google. Any ideas there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick way to determine if you can connect to the internet via R: using `RCurl::getURL`

```
if (is.character(getURL("www.google.com"))) {
   out <- TRUE
} else {
   out <- FALSE
}
```

from: < [How to determine if you have an internet connection in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076593/how-to-determine-if-you-have-an-internet-connection-in-r) ? >