# Command that allows re-checking TRUE/FALSE

Tags: r

How to write command (function) that would allow "endless loop" checking whether the internet connection is TRUE else wait and than check again and so on....

Here is attempt what I mean:

```
havingIP <- function() { if (.Platform$OS.type == "windows") {
ipmessage <- system("ipconfig", intern = TRUE) } else { 
ipmessage <- system("ifconfig", intern = TRUE) }
validIP <- "((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)[.]){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)"
any(grep(validIP, ipmessage)) }
```

The source for the above solution and credit goes here:

[How to determine if you have an internet connection in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076593/how-to-determine-if-you-have-an-internet-connection-in-r)

```
if(havingIP()){ source(....) } else { for(i in 1:5) { Sys.sleep(1); cat(i) }}
```

Something like this but this is not appropriate since I want to execute the command `source` only once.

```
while(TRUE){ 
if(havingIP()){ print("working") } else { for(i in 1:5) { Sys.sleep(1);  
cat(i) }}  
}
```

So how to run this without `loop` that would check every 5sec and if the internet connection is not on wait another 5sec and so on until the internet is on, then execute the `source` only once and that's it.

Sorry I tried to search for this solution, I'm sure someone has asked something similar but could not find anything since I'm not sure how to search for it anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you might be looking for [`break`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Control.html):

```
while (TRUE) {
    if (havingIP()) {
        print("working") # execute what you want here
        break            # and if we ever reach here, then exit the while loop
    } else {
        for (i in 1:5) {
            Sys.sleep(1)
            cat(i)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A simpler take on lee's answer:

```
while(!havingIP()) for(i in 1:5) {Sys.sleep(1); cat(i)}
source(...)
```

This will pause execution until `havingIP` returns TRUE.