# RISmed package error: cannot open the connection

Tags: r, mesh, pubmed

I'm trying to use the RISmed package to extract data from the PubMed scientific database. I have used the exact same procedure before, but now I can't get it to work. The example below is a toy example.

> > library(RISmed)
> >
> > res <- EUtilsSummary("pinkeye", type="esearch", db="pubmed", datetype='pdat', mindate=2000, maxdate=2015, retmax=500)
>
> Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
>
> > QueryCount(res)
>
> Error in QueryCount(res) : object 'res' not found

The 'QueryCount(res)' is supposed to return the number of hits found using the query, but since it didn't find a connection, it didn't find any hits.

I have [checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076593/how-to-determine-if-you-have-an-internet-connection-in-r) if R has an internet connection and it seems like it does ; my mac also doesn't seem to have any issues. Does anyone else get this error, too? Do you know how to solve it?

Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Output of `traceback()` and `sessionInfo()` could shed more light on the cause of error

Comment: Here it works `res;
[1] "pinkeye[All Fields] AND 2000[PDAT] : 2015[PDAT]"`

Comment: @Osssan traceback() gives the following:  3: file(con, "r")
2: readLines(url, warn = FALSE, encoding = encoding) at <tmp>#7
1: EUtilsSummary("pinkeye", type = "esearch", db = "pubmed", datetype = "pdat", 
       mindate = 2000, maxdate = 2015, retmax = 500)

Answer (score 0):

Updating the package and restarting R did the trick!

I tried updated the package several times before but forgot to restart R.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could add one line like `Sys.sleep(0.1)` in your code to pause 0.1s before sending the next request of searching. It worked for me.