# R - Coding an internet speed test

Tags: r, connection, rcurl, geturl, speed-test

On occasion, I have a spotty internet connection or a severely reduced internet connection and I would like to automate web scraping activities.  Often times I download files with R, ranging from very small size to several GB.  Obviously, if you have a reduced internet connection speed, larger files will take a very long time to download.  It would be useful to have this information in R, as a check for proceeding with webscraping.

**I'd like to create a script or function in R that is capable of outputting an average internet speed.  Is this possible?**

I've seen threads that allow you to [determine if you have an active internet connection in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076593/how-to-determine-if-you-have-an-internet-connection-in-r).  They seem to employ ideas of testing for an internet connection using the `RCurl::getURL` or they use `system` calls for `ipconfig`.  One person also found a solution using DNS lookup.

Comment: (a) what OS do you run? (b) do you have a server you can run a process on? (c) are you ok with a `system()` call to another script?

Comment: a) Windows 7, b) I do not have a server, c) I could be ok with a `system()`call from R, but the reason for my post is to find any and all ways to achieve a possible speed test.  I assume a system call could accomplish this, but are there other ways?

Answer (score 3):

If you are happy with latency then I would suggest using ping:

```
install.packages(pingr)
library(pingr)
lolz<-ping("132.204.3.57")
```

You can use `if (lolz < 60) { download(...) }` before you download command to avoid downloading when your ping to the server hosting the files is terrible.

Comment: Testing with ICMP packets or small TCP packets (for the port-versions of functions in `pingr` is not going to provide representative data for actual downloads).

Answer (score 1):

The package {[speedtest](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/speedtest)} can do tha for you. It is currently under development.

```
# install package
install.packages("speedtest", repos = "https://cinc.rud.is")
library(speedtest)
library(pingr)

# test speed
speedtest::spd_test()
```